# How can I write unit tests that don't require resetting state?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to write a Vue.js app that uses VueX to build a simple counter app. (The app was generated with the `npx vue-cli init webpack app` command)

[image]

I wrote unit tests but found that they require I zero out the state manually at the beginning of a test. To be more specific, if I run the `decrement` test individually, (`$ yarn unit --testNamePattern='decrement'`), things work. If I run all the tests, the store is not reset and my code fails (a prior test leaves the store with a non-zero counter). I would really love to write the tests so that I don't have to do something inside my app code to reset. Since the store is an implementation detail I obviously don't want to reset it directly inside my test and have to mock something like VueX.

My vue component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="countly">
    <div class="app-name item">Countly</div>
    <div class="tally item">Tally:
      <span class="count">{{ count }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    <button class="increment" @click="increment">+</button>
    <button class="decrement" @click="decrement">-</button>
    <button class="zero" @click="zero">0</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { store } from '../store/Countly'

export default {
  name: 'Countly',
  computed: {
    count () {
      return store.state.count
    }
  },
  methods: {
    decrement: function () { store.commit('decrement') },
    increment: function () { store.commit('increment') },
    zero: function () { store.commit('zero') }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.countly {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.item {
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.tally {
  font-size: 1.15em;
}
button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 6em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 0px;
}
</style>
```

The store looks like this:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.use(Vuex)

export const mutations = {
  increment: state => state.count++,
  decrement: state => {
    // console.log( "Before: ", state.count )
    state.count--
    // console.log( "After: ", state.count )
  },
  zero: state => (state.count = 0) // eslint-disable-line no-return-assign
}

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations
})
```

I have a test for `decrement` that only works if I run it individually.

```
  it('should decrement', () => {
    // Serious hack. These tests don't start the mounted component from a fresh
    // state. If you run this test individually without the zero() call, they
    // work. But, if you run them with all the other tests, they fail because
    // state is retained from a previous state. Trying to mount with different options
    // (like attactToDocument or localVue) does not affect this. So, we need to call
    // zero to make sure things are in a good state first.
    //  console.log('Count is (should be zero when we first mount, right?!?!): ', getCount(vm))
    zero(vm) // Ugly hack
    decrement(vm)
    decrement(vm)
    expect(getCount(vm)).toEqual('-2')
  })
```

The entire test suite is here:

```
// import Vue from 'vue'
import Countly from '@/components/Countly'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'

describe('Countly.vue', () => {
  const increment = vm => vm.find('button.increment').trigger('click')
  const decrement = vm => vm.find('button.decrement').trigger('click')
  const zero = vm => vm.find('button.zero').trigger('click')

  const getCount = vm => {
    const count = vm.find('.count')
    const rv = count.text()
    return rv
  }

  let vm
  beforeEach(() => {
    vm = mount(Countly)
    // , {
    //   attachToDocument: true
    //   // localVue: true
    // })
    // zero() // If we don't zero it each time, it leaves state in the component...
  })
  // Need this because Vue does not correctly remount each time.
  // afterEach(() => {
  //   vm.destroy()
  // })

  it('should render correct contents', () => {
    const result = vm.find('.app-name')
    expect(result.text()).toEqual('Countly')
  })

  it('should start at 0', () => {
    expect(getCount(vm)).toEqual('0')
  })

  it('should increment', () => {
    increment(vm)
    expect(getCount(vm)).toEqual('1')
  })

  it('should decrement', () => {
    // Serious hack. These tests don't start the mounted component from a fresh
    // state. If you run this test individually without the zero() call, they
    // work. But, if you run them with all the other tests, they fail because
    // state is retained from a previous state. Trying to mount with different options
    // (like attactToDocument or localVue) does not affect this. So, we need to call
    // zero to make sure things are in a good state first.
    //  console.log('Count is (should be zero when we first mount, right?!?!): ', getCount(vm))
    // zero(vm) // Ugly hack
    decrement(vm)
    decrement(vm)
    expect(getCount(vm)).toEqual('-2')
  })

  it('should zero', () => {
    increment(vm)
    increment(vm)
    zero(vm)
    expect(getCount(vm)).toEqual('0')
  })
})
```

I have unit tests for the store as well.

```
import { mutations } from '@/store/Countly'

// destructure assign `mutations`
const { increment, zero, decrement } = mutations

describe('mutations', () => {
  it('increment', () => {
    const state = { count: 0 }
    increment(state)
    expect(state.count).toEqual(1)
  })

  it('decrement', () => {
    const state = { count: 0 }
    decrement(state)
    expect(state.count).toEqual(-1)
  })

  it('zero', () => {
    const state = { count: 5 }
    zero(state)
    expect(state.count).toEqual(0)
  })
})
```

In case it matters, the jest.config.js file looks like this:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'json',
    'vue'
  ],
  testURL: 'http://example.com',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest'
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/test/e2e'
  ],
  snapshotSerializers: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue'],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/test/unit/setup'],
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/test/unit/coverage',
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,vue}',
    '!src/main.js',
    '!**/node_modules/**'
  ]
}
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "unit": "jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage",
    "unit-bare": "jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit test/e2e/specs",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^21.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jest": "^22.0.4",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^0.3.0",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.12",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "selenium-server": "^3.0.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-jest": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You should separate testing Vuex from testing your component. In the component tests, you simply test that the correct mutations are triggered with the expected params. When testing Vuex you test that on calling a particular method with some params it makes the correct mutations. Anything outside of that, you're testing Vue itself. You should only test your own code, not Vue.

Comment: I understand the concept of avoiding testing the framework. That's not what is happening here. I'm mounting a component, finding the DOM element by class, then checking that the value inside it is what I expect. I'm not testing the framework, I'm testing that the framework does the right thing and in this case the test setup doesn't work, even though I believe the app code does work correctly.

Comment: It is exactly what's happening. `increment` commits a mutation and you expect it to have an effect on the component. Don't do that. Mock the store's actions and only check they have been called with the expected parameters. These are unit tests, not end to end tests. Your unit is the component. Don't test anything outside of it. Then you can separately move to another unit: the store. Where you don't care who/what calls the methods. You just make sure the correct mutation is performed when a particular method is called with some params.

Comment: @Andrei is completely correct - The point of unit testing is that you should test everything in complete isolation, assuming any imports and external dependencies are essentially [black boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box). Ideally, you should be mocking everything that isn't literally defined in that file/class/whatever (including your global store and other components you're using in that file/class/whatever). If you want to test things together, write integration/acceptance/end-to-end tests.

Comment: This is partially a semantic problem. The vue CLI tools generate "unit" tests which are really not unit tests ex: (https://gist.github.com/xrd/224b06c56f63dc30b73597d801d5aff4). I'm new to Vue and assumed I could call them them "unit" tests since they are generated with that name; they really are "component" tests. Did either of you look at the tests above? I posted the mutations tests. Did I describe the problem that I want to write "component" tests which don't mock internals? These tests use "mount" implying in the DOM; I'm surprised it keeps state across mount calls. This seems buggy.